# Cypher Query doesn't return when adding simple WHERE statement

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to do some simple queries over my Neo4jDB.

When I do this:

```
MATCH (n1:Word{word: 'athlete'})-[r*]-(n2:Word) RETURN n2
```

The result comes instantly. Exactly 300 nodes with this structure are returned:

[image]

But when I try to filter these results with:

```
MATCH (n1:Word{word: 'athlete'})-[r*]-(n2:Word) WHERE n2.pos = 'NN' RETURN n2
```

The query processing never ends.

I've checked the syntax hundred times but everything seems ok for me. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the operator `CONTAINS` work instead of `=`. It might be because the field is a string.

Solved.